# How to extract the time component from timestamp column in SQL Loader's control file?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Hoping that someone may help me out.

Oracle Version: 19.3.0

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  DATE_STAMP         DATE,
  TIMESTAMP          TIMESTAMP(6)
)
```

Sample data in csv format is as follows

cat test.csv

2007/05/13,16:35:24

2007/05/13,18:00:51

Control File:

```
OPTIONS(skip=1)
LOAD DATA
        INFILE 'test.csv'
        BADFILE 'test.bad'
        INSERT INTO TABLE test
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        (
         date_stamp,
         timestamp      TIMESTAMP "HH24:MI:SS.FF2"
        )
```

While the data is loaded in the table, but it is not in the correct format.

Actual Result:

select DATE_STAMP, TIMESTAMP from test;

13-MAY-07   9/1/2023 4:35:24.000000 PM
13-MAY-07   9/1/2023 6:00:51.000000 PM

Note: For some reason the "9/1/2023" is being auto pre pended to the TIMESTAMP column.

Desired Result:

13-MAY-07   4:35:24.000000 PM
13-MAY-07   6:00:51.000000 PM

Thanks in advance.

rogers7942

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got it wrong.

Timestamp datatype - in Oracle - contains **date** and **time** components, not only time.

[Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-A3C0D836-BADB-44E5-A5D4-265BA5968483) documentation (search for "timestamp") says:

> **Year, month, and day values of date**, as well as **hour, minute, and second values** of time, where fractional_seconds_precision is the number of digits in the fractional part of the SECOND datetime field.

In other words, that's similar to `date` datatype which doesn't contain fractional seconds.

If you don't specify date (while converting string to timestamp), Oracle sets it to *first of current month*:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss.ff3';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_timestamp('22:36:18', 'hh24:mi:ss') result from dual;

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01.09.2023 22:36:18.000
```

(Today is 14.09.2023).

When you store timestamp value into a table, you then choose to **display** it differently, e.g. only date component or only time component, in any format you want. For example:

```
SQL> create table test (col timestamp);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (systimestamp);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

COL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
14.09.2023 22:38:33.233

SQL> select to_char(col, 'hh:mi:ss.ff3 pm') display from test;

DISPLAY
---------------
10:38:33.233 pm

SQL>
```

If you insist on storing only timestamp value, you'll have to use `varchar2` datatype and store value as a string, and that's one of bad things you could ever do. Never store date/timestamp values into anything but appropriate datatypes. Storing them as strings will cause problems, sooner or later.